# Default regex django uses to validate email

Tags: django, django-forms, django-email

recently, I started playing with Django and created a custom form for user registration. In that form to create the field for email I use something like

`email = forms.EmailField()`

I observed that address such as *a@a.a* is considered invalid by the form. Of course this is a nonsense email address. Nonetheless, I wonder how does Django checks for validity.

I found some topics on the net discussing how to check for validity of an email address but all of them were providing some custom ways. Couldn't find something talking about the django default validator.

In their [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) on the email filed they specify

> Uses EmailValidator to validate that the given value is a valid email address, using a moderately complex regular expression.

However that's not very specific so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Did you check source?

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Done and thanks :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

us should check docs here [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/emailfield-django-forms/#:~:text=EmailField%20in%20Django%20Forms%20is,max_length%20and%20min_length%20are%20provided](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/emailfield-django-forms/#:%7E:text=EmailField%20in%20Django%20Forms%20is,max_length%20and%20min_length%20are%20provided).

if u wanna check validation use clean function like this :

```
from django.forms.fields import EmailField

email = EmailField()

my_email = "a@a.a"


print(email.clean(my_email))
```

if your email is valid then this func return value else return validation error

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also interested in this, I would suggest looking up the implementation (django.core.validators) as was kindly suggested by *iklinac* in the comments.

In it, there is not just the source but also mentions about standards that were used to derive regexes that check if domain and literal have valid format.